# CentOS 5.5 Install Customization

Tags: install, centos, package-management, kickstart

I'm having a frustrating time with customizing my initial CentOS 5.5 installation. I want to have a specific set of the packages installed (e.g. I want Java and httpd but not OpenOffice or NewsServer) but each time I carefully go through all the customization screens on installation it seems to somewhat randomly select and deselect other options. I'm trying to write up a repeatable step-by-step doc but something isn't right.

I've tried picking just "Desktop - Gnome" or "Server GUI" or even none of them. Then I choose the "Customize now" option and go through each of the packages that I want. What's odd is what comes out after the reboot is different each time. Does it matter which default package group I choose if I'm going to customize the lists?

Another oddity happens if I try to customize after the fact. For instance, if I try to just remove OpenOffice, it removes Gnome as a side-effect. I didn't uncheck the Gnome box but it appears that since OpenOffice is dependent upon Gnome, it gets removed as well. This implies that I need to do a minimal install and build it up as needed.

Am I missing some core metaphor that the installer is using? I'm using the exact same DVD image each time so I'm confused why I'm having such different results. Also I'm using the graphical installation mode. Ideally I'd be able to create a kickstart config from a good install.

Any pointers would help.

Comment: If you want a repeatable installation, use Kickstart.

Comment: I'm trying to make a kickstart config script via the GUI but I'm not getting consistent results!

Comment: @mattdm : Sounds like he's trying to install a system first, so he has an anaconda-ks.cfg file to work from.

Comment: So, do it however, and then change the package selection to suit in the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had <strike>better</strike> responses over on Server Fault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/233036/centos-5-5-install-customization

Comment: Yeah. And most of those better responses say "If you want a repeatable installation, use Kickstart."

Comment: The difference is they actually give suggestions on best approaches...and they weren't sassy about it.